# My SVG won't scale

Tags: html, svg

[Update] I rephrased and got the perfect answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570401/how-to-size-an-svg-viewbox-with-angularjs/45571103)

I do not see this as being a duplicate of the question mentioned above, for reasons given below

---

I want a kiosk display, where a single browser tab is how, full-screen (press F11).

I want a left and right column, with an SVG image in the centre.

```
Here is a minimal implementation:

<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>blah</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1" style="width: 90%; margin: auto">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%">
                Left column
            </td>                       
            <td style="width:60%; border-width:1px; border-color:red;border-style: solid">
```

The SVG goes here, but is 1,300 lines

```
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%">
                Right column
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

</body>
```

as stated, the SVG is 1,300 lines, so I won't post it unless you *really* need it :-)

I believe that only the start is of interest, and that's what I can't seem to get right. How should my `SVG` tag look to fill that table cell with the SVG, scaled to fit, maintaining the height / width ratio?

It currently is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="7.22222in" height="10.0444in"
     viewBox="0 0 650 904">
```

with the rest of the file being `path` tags.

which is obviously wrong, as it has a fixed height / width. Note that I cannot foresee the screen size of the various kiosk devices.

---

[Update]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689678/make-svg-scale-to-full-screen-size) seems to imply that the viewBox must have a fixed size, rather than 100% - is that so?

Also, I have to inline the `SVG` (I don't know if that makes a difference). I can't use an HTML `img` tag because I am using AngularJs and some of my paths look like

```
   <path id="Top row 1" ng-click='RoomClicked($event, "A-1")'
        fill={{GetFillColour('A-1')}} stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 226.00,69.00
           C 226.00,69.00  ...
```

and when I use an `img` tag, the browser reports an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale SVG to container without mask/crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566792/scale-svg-to-container-without-mask-crop)

Comment: That was helpful  but the Fiddle given uses absolute pixel sizes, as does the `viewport` (which I don't quite understand).  - I require something that will work at any screen resolution. I am hoping that someone will post a fiddle using that code and an SVG of their choice.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689678/make-svg-scale-to-full-screen-size) seems to imply that the viewport must have a fixed size, rather than 100% - is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work for me (at least in Firefox) if I use an image tag pointing to an SVG, with the following CSS used:-

```
#container img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Where container is a flexible div constraining the size of the SVG (this could be your table cell). The SVG is filling the width of the container, with proportions kept in pro, but if the container gets too wide the max-height kicks in and restricts the height of the SVG as expected without stretching.

Answer (score -4):

Just take out the width and height attributes and you should be fine.

Comment: When I do that, I don't see any SVG at all (maybe the viewport?)

Comment: Removing the height and width will almost certainly mean that the size falls back to 300 x 150 the "help I've no idea what size I'm supposed to be" size for a replaced element.