# How to size an SVG viewBox with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, svg

Solutions to similar questions involve CSS and the `img` tag.

However, I cannot use the `<img src="myFile.svg">` because the SVG contains Angular directives, such as

```
  <path id="Top row 1" ng-click='RoomClicked($event, "A-1")'
        fill={{GetFillColour('A-1')}} stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 226.00,69.00
           C 226.00,69.00 226.00,136.00 226.00,136.00  ...
```

So, I thought to have the SVG inline, in a view, and to size the SVG viewBox according to its its container, because (***important***) the whole idea is that I want to be able to display the web page at any resolution and have the SVG scale to fit it's parent `DIV`.

So, I tried

```
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"         
         viewBox="0 0 {{GetSvgDivHeight()}} {{GetSvgDivWidth()}}">
```

in my view, and

```
$scope.GetSvgDivHeight = function() 
{
   height = Math.round(screen.height * 0.8);

   return height;
}

$scope.GetSvgDivWidth = function() 
{
   width = document.getElementById('SVG_goes_here').offsetWidth;

   return width;
}
```

in my controller.

But, the SVG does not show, and the developer console shows

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 Error: <svg> attribute viewBox: Expected number, "0 0 {{GetSvgDivHeigh…".
```

So, 1) can I set the size of my in line SVG's viewBox programactically, from `$scope`? 2) if not, how can I make the ***inline*** SVG, containing Angular directives, fill its parent DIV, and resize if that DIV is resized?

---

[Update]  InkScape generated

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="7.22222in" height="10.0444in"
     viewBox="0 0 650 904">
```

when I change that to

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 650 904">
```

The image fills the width of the containing DIV, but only the top half shows and the browser tab grows a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewBox` describes *which part* of the SVG canvas to display. If, in SVG root coordinates, the left/upper border is at (0,0) and the right/lower at (300,200), set `viewBox="0 0 300 200"`.

To set the *display* size of the SVG, use `width` and `height`. Setting both to 100% suffices to make it fit into the `<div>`. Even better, they are the default values, so you can leave them off. Note that HTML blocks have no intrinsic height, so you still need to restrict that to screen size.

If you start out with a external SVG that does not set `viewBox`, but (some of) `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">
```

move them into the `viewBox` for the inline element, remove the `width` attribute and set the computed screen-related height:

```
<div style="position:relative;height:{{GetSvgDivHeight()}}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
```

or (Angular 1.x syntax)

```
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         ng-attr-height="{{GetSvgDivHeight()}}" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
```

The need for the `ng-attr-height=` workaround is explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes) and was the reason for the original error message. For Angular 2+, use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding): `[attr.height]=`

Comment: That's the clearest description of the viewBox that I ever read. But, when I set the height to 100%, only the top half of the image showed. Please see the update to the question (at the bottom). Sounds like you can help me with a simple correction (fingers crossed).

Comment: aah yes...divs have no intrinsic height...you'll have to set either the div or the SVG height. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It looked like we were getting closer ... But, now I am back to the original problem  `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     height="{{GetSvgDivHeight()}}"` gives `Error: <svg> attribute height: Expected length, "{{GetSvgDivHeigh…".` in the browser console :-(

Comment: return `height + "px"` from your function. Angular is pretty peculiar about what it considers to be valid HTML.

Comment: It's returning `450px`, but I am still getting the same error :-(  I don't understand that

Comment: I've never used Angular v2+, but I've just seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571792) syntax: `[attr.height] ="fn()"` (stab in the dark)

Comment: I ought to have said that I am using 1.6. Looks like I need to think in another direction - maybe HTML canvas. I really don't know. This is frustrating

Comment: I think I found it: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

Comment: I think that you ***did*** find it !!!!  Just as soon as the system allows a bounty, I shall award one. I take my head covering off to you, sir!

Answer (score 2):

The bounty has (quite rightly) been awarded, but adding this answer as a resolution in my case wasn't immediately clear.

In my case, the `ng-attr-viewBox` was being inappropriately lower-cased.  The solution for this is described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes), and repeated here for posterity.

> If one wants to modify a camelcased attribute (SVG elements have valid
>   camelcased attributes), such as viewBox on the svg element, one can
>   use underscores to denote that the attribute to bind to is naturally
>   camelcased.
>
> For example, to bind to viewBox, we can write:
>
> `<svg ng-attr-view_box="{{viewBox}}"> </svg>`